# Can't change Qt version from 5.12.8 to 5.15.X

Tags: compiling, qt, version

I've tried building packages from qt's website but everytime I try to cmake a specific file that requests qt version 5.15 I'm always told it fails because I'm using the default version 5.12.8. How can I make it so I'm using a new version of qt? APT packages don't seem to solve the issue.

I'm attempting to cmake some libs from the kde api repo because I can't find them on my computer and this issue is preventing that. I would like to finish building that kdeconnect app via vscode.

running `qmake version` gives me

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: qt 5.15 : Debian 11 and Ubuntu 21.04 have qt-5.15.2

Comment: i'm using linux mint 20.2

Comment: Well, the hint about another OS was to tell it's much easier to install an additional OS w qt-5.15.2 than it is to install a complete qt-5.15.2 install to a "hide-away-location" on Mint 20.2 .

Comment: i'm considering it. A more popular distro might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Qt forum:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/Qt/6.1.2/gcc_64/lib/cmake  CMakeLists.txt
```

you can use a specific version of Qt as such. The path should be accurate to wherever you've installed your Qt directory.